# How to use setprogressbar() on a progressbar with style Widget.ProgressBar.Large

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, widget

I want to show progress in a widget via a wheel-progressbar (not the horizontal one).
This is the progressbar in the xml layoutfile, that shows the content to the user:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"/>
```

In the appwidget_provider implementation I wanted to set the progressbar like this:

`RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.sample_widget);
    views.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar1, 2, 1, false);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);`

(sample_widget being the layout shown to the user)

Now, if progressBar1 is a horizontal progressBar, everything is displayed as you would expect.
But if I use any other style, like here, the progressbar is not displayed as soon as setProgressBar() sets indeterminate to false.

I presume that is because the wheel-progressbars are apparently designed to show only indeterminate behaviour, so the drawable for determinate behaviour does not exist, which
leads to the progressbar not being displayed.("If you will use the progress bar to show real progress, you must use the horizontal bar.", according to the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html))

My question is now how I would go about making a wheel-progressbar that is capable of
showing actual progress ? Furthermore I wanted to be able to customize the progressbar based
on user preferences or how much progress has currently been made ( maybe dynamically change the colour of the bar, make it brighter/darker, bolder/thinner, etc.).

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction, because I assume I am pretty much overthinking it now.I believe there must be a simple way of doing it, I just did not find anything on the matter.

Comment: https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar